# Default image avatar depending on gender

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to create kind of profiles with default avatars.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)

class Someone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    gender = models.Charfield(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default=someone_avatar)
```

I'm trying to write a function which returns path to my folder with jpg.

```
def someone_avatar(instance):
    gender = instance.gender
    if gender == 'Male':
        avatar = 'avatars/m.jpg'
    else:
        avatar = 'avatars/f.jpg'
    return avatar
```

Obviously it doesn't work, so could you give me some advise how to solve it?
Maybe I should overwrite save method?
Thx.

## Edited

Ok, I tried with post_save but it does't work as well:

```
def set_avatar(instance):
    avatar = instance.image
    gender = instance.gender
    if gender == 'Male':
        avatar = 'persons/m.jpg'
    else:
        avatar = 'persons/f.jpg'
    return avatar

def post_save_avatar(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if not instance.image:
         instance.image = set_avatar(instance)
post_save.connect(post_save_avatar, sender=Person)
```

Maybe I shouldn't just set avatar to string like path?

## Edit 2

It's working for pre_save.

Comment: Yeah, `pre_save` is better anyway, since `post_save` would make and additional `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save). It gives you `created` flag. So you can manually set your desired image in your handler if `created` is True.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you can use clean method in django model to validate fields, sometimes they are used to modify model field to specific values based on the condition meet.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
('M', 'Male'),
('F', 'Female'),
)

class Someone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    gender = models.Charfield(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    
    def clean(self):
       if self.gender == 'M':
           self.image = "profile/boy_default.png"
       else:
           self.image = "profile/girl_default.png"
```

You can refer [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for more